# How can i solve spaces problems?

Tags: html, css

i'm not so good at programming but i'm making a website for a friend
and i'm having problems with spaces under my elements like this print:

1- http://prntscr.com/f02fan

2- http://prntscr.com/f02ff8

I think this spaces is there because i'm using CSS's commands to adjust the elements like this:

```css
position: relative;
bottom: 3889px;
left: 1055px;
```

```html
<a href="Resina_Llis.html" class="button style1" style="position: relative; bottom: 3889px; left: 1055px;">Ver detalhes</a>
```

If someone have a better way to do this or to remove the spaces please tell me.Thanks

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab.

Comment: remove those `bottom: 3889px; left: 1055px;`..... really

Comment: @DanielH but if i remove this code the button will be at other position.How can i put 2 itens side by side without this code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach, use `display: flex;`. Note that IE broswer older than IE11 are not supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}
.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.</div>
</div>
```

A really simple example to put two div item side by side.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  /* removing the default ul margin */
  padding: 0;
  /* removing the default ul padding */
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
}

.left {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="left half">foo</li>
  <li class="right half">bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @LuhanSalimena I updated, added another way might be better for you to use flex, but depend on your user base (IE broswer older than IE11 are not supported)

Comment: Ok, as soons as i got home i'll try it

Comment: I've tryed your code and it seems ok except for the fact that i don't know how can i center this Titles and buttons: http://prntscr.com/f0c5kn

Comment: @LuhanSalimena which approach you used? 1st or 2nd one? I could update to show you how to center those, do you have the html for those item? or the code to generate them, just need to see the layout of your html code

Comment: Where can i send you a private message ?

Comment: @LuhanSalimena I will take a look tonight

Comment: @LuhanSalimena few things: 1st I added `<h2 style=" text-decoration: line-through; color: gray;">&nbsp;</h2>` to your right image, event you don't have a discount price, you should still place that tag with `&nbsp;` as a placeholder, otherwise left will be higher than right.

Comment: @LuhanSalimena 2nd things I move your `img` style to a class called `itemstyle` to make left and right same height, I set the `img` with `      height: 350px; width: auto;` so the img have fixed height but vary on width based on img's ratio etc.